# Rspec test in rails fails with nilclass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

EDIT: Here is the working answer:

```
it "redirects to the show view for the object that was selected" do
  object_id = params[:object][:id]
  get :select, object: { id: object_id }
  expect(subject).to redirect_to object_path(params[:object][:id])
end
```

I have an rspec test in a rails app that is failing and I can't figure out why (rspec noob).

I am not supposed to use Factory Girl, so please don't give answers that rely on that.

Here is the controller code:

```
def select
  redirect_to object_path(params[:object][:id])
end
```

This is referencing an object selected from a collection select in the view:

```
<%= form_tag select_object_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= collection_select(:object, :id, Object.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Select One:") %>
  <br>
  <%= submit_tag "View Object" %>
<% end %>
```

The test code:

```
describe "GET #select" do
  let(:object) do
    Object.create(name: "Object Name", description: "This is an object")
  end

  let(:params) do
    {
    object: {
      id: "1",
      name: "An Object",
      description: "Object object"
      }
    }
  end

  it "redirects to the show view for the object that was selected" do
    object_id = params[:object][:id]
    get :select, id: object_id
    expect(subject).to redirect_to object_path
  end
end
```

The error message:

```
Failures:

 1) ObjectsController GET #select redirects to the show view for the object that was selected
 Failure/Error: redirect_to object_path(params[:object][:id])

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/objects_controller.rb:45:in `select'
 # ./spec/controllers/objects_controller_spec.rb:100:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've tried a bunch of different tests and nothing seems to pass. It seems to think that params[:object][:id] is nil but I can't figure out why as it should be equal to 1. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Have used the website and verified that the functionality seems to work but I just can't figure out how to test it. The params look like this:

"object"=>{"id"=>"1"}

Comment: You have error in code. You are missing " in the text  name: An Object" . Please first correct it and try again.

Comment: Ah sorry that was a typo in this question but not in the actual code (real app uses something else besides Object). Fixed it in question but that is not the problem.

Comment: Add debugger in select method and try to check what is value of params

Answer (score 3):

```
get :select, id: object_id
```

You make a GET request and pass id=1 as a parameter.

```
redirect_to object_path(params[:object][:id])
```

In `select` action you try to get this id from `object` parameter, but you didn't send it. So you call `params[:object]` and get `nil`. Then you call `nil[:id]` and get the exception.

To solve the problem pass parameters like so:

```
get :select, object: { id: object_id }
```

Or get the id directly:

```
redirect_to object_path(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks, this was close and helped me get it to work! I had to change both the parameters passed and the params in the redirect_to path, but I had to use params[:object][:id] there. Working test:  



    it "redirects to the show view for the object that was selected" do
      object_id = params[:object][:id]
      get :select, object: { id: object_id }
      expect(subject).to redirect_to object_path(params[:object][:id])
    end